# 12.10: login screen never goes blank

Tags: login-screen

I have installed the 12.10 beta (with all updates) on my iMac Early 2008. One annoying problem I'm having is that, when I log out of my account and go back to the login screen (lightdm, per default), the screen stays on: it never goes blank. This is not good for my display I guess!

The screensaver (set to just a blank screen) works just fine when I'm logged in. The problem only appears at the login screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are using an old CRT screen, no harm will be done to your display. LCD displays do not need screensavers.

Comment: Thanks... I would still feel more comfortable if my screen went blank though. Also, I assume it saves some power, no?